# Redirect subdomain to folder infinitely redirects due to www rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a single subdomain to an existing website. We've added the appropriate 'A' record. We want `staging.example.com` to display the contents from `example.com/test/` (and remain `staging.example.com`).

The `.htaccess` file (written by someone else) redirects all non-https to https, and all non-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Rewrite http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

#Rewrite non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried to add a line like the following, just before the last `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging\.(.+)$ [NC]
```

However, it always gets in a redirect loop to `www.staging.example.com` ...

Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Does `staging.example.com` already display the contents from `example.com/test/`? It is just the canonical redirection that is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are directing BACK to HTTP with your WWW redirect.  Change it to `https:`

**EDIT**

I would also invert your statments .. This is EXACTLY what I use --  And I can verify it works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
# to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I tried what you suggested and am still getting the error. Is it possible that it's being cached? I have been using Chrome incognito, I cleared my cache, and flushed DNS ... ?